# How to prevent the auto complete of a UserForm ComboBox?

Tags: excel, userform, vba

When I'm typing in a ComboBox in an Excel UserForm, for example I have a list item called `SHEEP` (all uppercase), then if I want to add another item called `Shear` (only the first letter is uppercase), the program will force it to look like this: `SHEar`

I do not want to disable the auto completing feature though, just not overwrite the upper/lower case typed by the keyboard.

The combo books is as shown below:
[image: Userform]

Comment: I wonder why this got down-voted. Sounds like a legit question to me, has an example and has to do with programming.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ It's difficult to find what is really appropriate to post over here. Although if I can get some progress it's all that matters to me despite getting downvotes. I try my best not to spam though. I google first then try to search it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to prevent this is to disable matching of the entries.
Therefore you need to set the [MatchEntry Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/matchentry-property) of the ComboBox.

In the *Properties* window change the `MatchEntry` property to `2` - `fmMatchEntryNone`.

Alternatively you can use a TextBox to add a new entry into the ComboBox.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it out and noticed it doesn't auto-complete anymore. So I guess that's the trade off. I'll just probably make it all caps lock so that there won't be a problem

Comment: @MarcSantos Alternatively use a TextBox to enter and add the new entry as a trade-off.

Comment: Although the code in the combobox will detect if the item is not in the listbox, then if it isn't it should add it. Having an auto-complete is good so the user won't duplicate entries. It's shown in the photo I added above

Comment: Well, you can sort out duplicates by letting your code check that before you perform the add. Personally I would add a small button behind the ComboBox triggering an InputBox to add a new entry. This would leave the ComboBox a simple select only box and the user cannot accidentally add new entries. He has to explicitly decide to add one by the button.

Comment: I put a `Msgbox` with a `vbQuestion+vbYesNo` Then make an `If-Then` statement to ask for clarification to minimize accidents. Also, sometimes there are many variations of a certain entry such as `Communication, Lights, and Water` or `Communication, Light, and Water` and I want the user to see that it already exists because the sorting may probably be bypassed if i'm not mistaken

Comment: @MarcSantos I understand your concerns but I suspect there is no perfect solution.

Comment: It's good to know you can disable to auto complete feature though. I'll just workaround it by making all capitalized. The users always have caps lock on anyway